# check whether NFC Is active when camera is on in Android

Tags: android, camera, nfc

I've made a screen where camera and nfc is used together but have found out that some devices or after Android 11, NFC seems to get blocked when camera is used.

Therefore, I was trying to implement where if NFC is blocked, I was trying to show a text in the screen that NFC is blocked due to camera but have a hard time checking if NFC is active or not.

Is there a way I can check is NFC is blocked or not when using a camera?

Finding a way the check if NFC is active or not when using a camera

Answer (score 0):

I've not had any Android 11 device to find this myself and it depends on what the camera is doing to block/disable NFC but there is a Broadcast Receiver for the state of NFC

e.g.

```
// Listen to NFC setting changes
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    // Listen for NFC being turned on while in the App
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED)) {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ADAPTER_STATE,
                        NfcAdapter.STATE_OFF);
                switch (state) {
                    case NfcAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                    // Tell the user to turn NFC on if App requires it
                        break;
                    case NfcAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                        break;
                    case NfcAdapter.STATE_ON:
                        // Enabled NFC;
                        break;
                    case NfcAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
```