How to detect NFC Enable/disable from device settings in Android/Flutter
I am creating an App for NFC HCE in Flutter. I want to notify the user when NFC is disabled from device settings.
I have tried platform channel to detect this, but when I turn off NFC from settings, then it claims that NFC is not supported, even when my device does have NFC.
My methods:
 private fun Context.isNfcAvailable(): Boolean {
        return NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this) != null
    }
 private fun Context.isNfcEnabled(): Boolean {
        val nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)
        return nfcAdapter?.isEnabled ?: false
    }


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618657/how-to-check-whether-nfc-is-enabled-or-not-in-android#:~:text=nfc%22%20android%3Arequired%3D%22,NFC%20is%20currently%20turned%20on.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#isEnabled()

Can you try this answer is it working or not?

There is a broadcast receiver to get notified when NFC state changes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74314623/2373819 as a Java example.
